# Seed dispersal around a tree provokes an infinite loop?

Tags: netlogo

I've just started a project in which I intend to simulate (among other things) the seed dispersal around trees (named zsps). Neighboring patches can already be settled or unable for seeding due to low fertility.
I wrote code that runs (at the begining of simulation) but that made the code enter into an infinite loop (I think) because some trees attempt to spread seeds but cannot find any available place.

Does anyone have a solution to escape from this trap (in case the number of places is < the number of seeds or in case there are no places at all)?

Here is the procedure I wrote :

```
to check-seed-dispersal
  ask zsps[
    let nb-seeds 0
    ifelse (age > 4) [set NFemFlowers 100] 
    [set NFemFlowers 0]
    let temp-color color
    if Tot_pol > 0
    [set nb-seeds round ((NFemFlowers / Tot_pol) * 6 ) ]
    if (nb-seeds > 0 )[     
      ask patches in-radius 5 with [fertility > 8 and not any? zsps-here]   
      [sprout-zsps  nb-seeds 
        [ifelse (temp-color = yellow)
          [set color gray set age 0 ] 
          [set color red  set age 0 ] 
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! At a glance, it doesn't look like there's anything to cause an actual loop in your code; if the conditions of an `if` statement are not satisfied, that code is just not executed. However, it's hard to properly check without a working example- you may want to have a look at the [SO asking help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), specifically the section on creating a [minimum example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), to help get your question sorted out.